# Custom category URL wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, permalinks, taxonomy

Can you help me with one issue? I want to understand how I can make WordPress URL like this structure. Examples:

```
http://sitename/category-1/subcat/article1
http://sitename/category-2/subcat/article2
http://sitename/category-3/subcat/article3
```

Searched all google but nothing found :(

General conditions is don't use any plugins or modify `functions.php`, only admin manipulations. Can anyone explain me how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming and is off topic for SO.  I would strongly suggest you look through the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) to actually learn about the CMS if you plan on regularly using it. Please note that it is expected that you to do some research before asking questions on here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about Wordpress administration/configuration

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply by adding the custom permalink as /%category%/%postname%/

[image]

Source: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/

Comment: Have you asked for the permission of the webmaster of wpbeginner.com to copy that screenshot to an external service?